# How to create a loop that maps network drives using an username and password in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Basically I would like to map a network drive, extract some info from there and move to the next one.
I am doing this using a batch script but I am limited when extracting the info.
Here is what I do with the batch script and it works pretty well the problems is it is extracting the line in the log while I want the line above too:

```batch
for /F "tokens=1" %%i in (computers_list.txt) do call :DL %%i
goto end
:DL

echo Triggering %1 >> output.log

net use Z: /delete /yes 
net use Z: \\computername\C$ /user:username  password 

findstr /n "retrieved" "Z:\logs\*.log" >> output.log

echo.  >> output.log
:end
```

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. What have you tried so far (show your PowerShell code), and what *particular* problem do you need help with?

Comment: Actually, I think I have a bigger problem. New-PSDrive : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Persist'. I will figure out something. Thank you for reminding me that this is not a free translation. If I would have had time to poke around I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: Again, please show your code (a [mcve] actually) and the exact error message(s). We're not sitting in front of your computer, so you need to relay to us what you're seeing. [Edit] your question to provide the information. Do not bury it in the comments.

Comment: I'd simply replace the findstr command with `powershell -NoP -C "Select-String -Path Z:\logs\*.log -Pattern 'retrieved' -Context 1|Set-Content output.log -Append"`

Comment: Thank you LotPings , It works fine with one exception -Append parameter is not supported by my PowerShell version. When I take it out it just wipes the previous records.

Comment: Then use `powershell -NoP -C "Select-String -Path Z:\logs\*.log -Pattern 'retrieved' -Context 1 >>output.log`  Albeit I'm not shure this is the reason, did you replace `net use Z: \\computername\C$ /user:username  password` with `net use Z: \\%1\C$ /user:username  password` to use the passed computername?

Comment: `Set-Content` doesn't have a parameter `-Append`. For appending use `Add-Content` or `Out-File -Append`. Note that the latter defaults to UTF-16 LE encoding whereas the former defaults to ASCII encoding. And maybe we could see some actual code to end the speculation?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, I used Add-Content and it worked fine. LotPings, I used it exactly the way you sent it and just changed Set-Content to Add-Content

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a fancier way to do it with regex, but that's for you to figure out :)

I think this will work for you.

```
Clear-Host

<#
    Contents of C:\Test.txt
    Server01
    Server02
    Server03
#>

$userName = 'domain\user'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'p@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $password
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\Test.txt'
$outputFile = 'C:\output.log'

If (Test-Path $outputFile)
{
  Remove-Item $outputFile -Force
}

Foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  $null = New-PSDrive -Name 'Z' -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root "\\$server\c$" -Credential $credentials

  $files = Get-Item -Path 'Z:\logs*.log'

  Foreach ($file in $files)
  {
    $fileContents = Get-Content $file

    $previousLine = 'No previous line'
    Foreach ($line in $fileContents)
    {
      If ($line -like '*retrieved*')
      {
        Add-Content -Value $previousLine -Path $outputFile
        Add-Content -Value $line -Path $outputFile
        Add-Content -Value ' ' -Path $outputFile
      }

      $previousLine = $line
    }
  }

  Remove-PSDrive -Name 'Z'
}

If (Test-Path $outputFile)
{
  Invoke-Item $outputFile
}
```

Comment: The `-context` feature of Select-String seems a lot easier as the logs are in one folder.

Comment: Yeah - I have never used that before, but it appears you are correct.